# What .NET libraries are available for sending instant messages?

Tags: .net, instant-messaging

What .NET libraries are available for sending instant messages?  If you have experience with them, what were your impressions?

Comment: Sorry, my bad got my wires crossed. I'll remove the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [DotMSN](http://www.xihsolutions.net/dotmsn/) for MSN Messenger.  It worked quite well and was easy to use.

Comment: There are some useful links there, as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used Jabber-Net (for XMPP) and it has worked fine. 
http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/